# perl how to convert a string to Datetime?

Tags: perl, datetime

I tried to convert a string to date in perl, but get error.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;  
use DateTime;  
use Date::Manip;

my $date = ParseDate("20111121");
print "today is ".$date->day_of_week."\n";
```

error

```
Can't call method "day_of_week" without a package or object reference
```

Looks like the package import has problem ...

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

DateTime doesn't parse dates.  I'd go for the [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) core module that gives you strptime():

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime("20111121", "%Y%m%d");
print $t->strftime("%w\n");
```

Comment: Why, when there's a core module, do people recomend using DateTime for simple date operations with perl? (I'm new to perl, this is a genuin question)

Comment: @Relequestual `DateTime` offers the ability to compute date durations (e.g. the number of days between two dates) among other things.  Perhaps its most important feature is it works with calendars instead of times.  Hence, you can compute the value of "yesterday" without regard to Daylight Saving and non-existent times.  See the module documentation and [FAQ4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-find-yesterday%27s-date?)

Answer (score 30):

DateTime itself has no parsing facility, but there are many [parsers](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=DateTime%3A%3AFormat&mode=module) that gererate DateTime objects. Most of the time, you'll probably want [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime).

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );
my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y%m%d',
   time_zone => 'local',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);
my $dt = $format->parse_datetime('20111121');
```

Or you could do it yourself.

```
use DateTime qw( );
my ($y,$m,$d) = '20111121' =~ /^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\z/
   or die;
my $dt = DateTime->new(
   year      => $y,
   month     => $m,
   day       => $d,
   time_zone => 'local',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the module documentation: [This module does not parse dates](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/lib/DateTime.pm#Parsing_Dates)

You need to add code such as suggested in [I printed a date with strftime, how do I parse it again?](https://github.com/houseabsolute/DateTime.pm/wiki/Basic-Usage#i-printed-a-date-with-strftime-how-do-i-parse-it-again) to convert from a string to a date time object.

Comment: I change to this, still doesn't work. use DateTime;  

my $dateStr = '20111121';
my $year  = substr ($dateStr,0,4);
my $month = substr ($dateStr,4,2);
my $day   = substr ($dateStr,6,2);
print $year . "/".$month."/".$day."\n"

my $date = DateTime->new(
      year      => $year,
      month     => $month,
      day       => $day,   
  );