# Convert string to date with DateTime::Format::Strptime

Tags: perl

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218857/1084945), I'm using `DateTime::Format::Strptime` to grab the date from a string.

I'm using the following pattern: `%m%d%Y%n%T`. This [should be matching](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Format-Strptime-1.52/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm):

- `%m`: The month number (01-12). This will parse single digit numbers as well.
- `%d`: The day of month (01-31). This will parse single digit numbers as well.
- `%Y`: The year, including century (for example, 1991).
- `%n`: Arbitrary whitespace.
- `%T`: Equivalent to `%H:%M:%S`:

  - `%H`: The hour (00-23). This will parse single digit numbers as well.
  - `%M`: The minute (00-59). This will parse single digit numbers as well.
  - `%S`: The second (0-60; 60 may occur for leap seconds. See `DateTime::LeapSecond`).

However, on input: [`05/18/2011 14:14:05`] it's failing with the error:

> Your datetime does not match your pattern

As far as I can see, my pattern matches the input pattern. Where am I going wrong?

Relevant code is below:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%m%d%Y%n%T',
   time_zone => 'local',
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $fields->[1] ;
print "Date:[$dt]\n";
my $dateopen = $format->parse_datetime($dt);
```

Output:

> Date:[05/18/2011 14:14:05]
>   Your datetime does not match your pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-pattern characters are important as well. You have slashes between your date components, hence the pattern `'%m/%d/%Y%n%T'` works while yours doesn't.

Note that the pattern `%D` would not work either as it is a shortcut for `%m%d%Y` and doesn't include the slashes either.